# How to configure TFS build-definition for continous-intergration for a PHP-Project on Windows Azure Webrole?

Tags: php, azure, tfs, continuous-integration

I am running a PHP Project (Drupal-Multisite-Enviroment) on Azure web-role with WindowsAzurePHP SDK. Everything works pretty fine. Now I want to implement continuous-integration with TFS and i am wondering, if anybody has ever done it before, because i can't find any documentation about it.

I understand that the deployment process on Azure is connected to the build process on TFS. But what is the output of that azure-specific build-process? The deployment package *.cspkg and ServiceConfiguration.cscfg?

If so, do i just have to make a custom Build, that moves PHP files to a temp folder, calls the Azure SDK package-batch and pushes the package to Azure cloud afterwards?

I would appreciate it if you would share your experiences with me.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done it before but yes... If you set your solution to build in Team Build you should get the Azure specific output only.

The easiest to get your PHP into the right place is with a pre or post build PowerShell.

https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities/blob/master/Source/Scripts/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1

You should be able to use this PowerShell after build to put together your PHP with your azure bits that just got built.

Then create a post test PowerShell to deploy to Azure.

You can set PowerShell scripts to run by editing the build definitions and on the process tab opening the "advanced" sections.

Note: Make sure that you are using DefaulTemplate.12.xaml.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i appreciate it! Sadly, i don't have the setup anymore to try this out. If someone confirms your answer i will accept it! :)